# Get Data from websites for android live score app

Tags: java, android, extract

i'm developing an app for android which is just like `SofaScore`.
but the point is that i don't have any `API`. also free `APIs` on internet have some limitations that makes them not suitable for me.
so i decided to extract data from live score websites. my questions are

1. is it possible to get live data from websites?
2. i just know java and android developing, in order to extract data,
   should i learn a new language?

Comment: you could get data from a webpage, but that would require parsing the page structure. The structure may change at any time, without notice, making your app unusable. I would advise you to continue searching for API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just create a Mock-API with the structure and everything that you need, that would be more reliable in the long run!